# Can this piece of matlab script be vectorized further?

Tags: optimization, matlab, vectorization

So what I am trying to do with this code is find all pixels on a line of an image that are below a certain threshold. The problem, however, is that this code is executed in a double for loop (yeah I know :( ), once for each pixel, so it's very slow. I'm wondering if there's anything else I can do.

Some tips would be great, as I'm pretty new to MATLAB optimization, and I know only the basics (try not to use loops, or call scripts many times in inner functions, etc). If this doesn't work out, I might have to resort to MEX files, and that'll be harder to maintain for the other researchers in my group. Thank you!

```
for y = 1:y_len
    for x = 1:x_len
        %//...do stuff to calc slope and offset for the line, 
                %//this can be vectorized pretty easily.

        yIndices = xIndices.*slope + offset;
        yIndices = round(yIndices);

        yIndices = yIndices + 1;
        xIndices = xIndices + 1;
        valid_points = (yIndices <= 308) & (yIndices > 0);

        %this line is bottle necking----------------------------------------
        valid_points = yIndices(valid_points)+(xIndices(valid_points)-1)*308;
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------

        valid_points = valid_points(phaseMask_R(valid_points));
        t_vals = abs(phase_R(valid_points)-currentPhase);
        point_vals = [XsR(valid_points);YsR(valid_points)] - 1;
        matchedPtsCoordsR = point_vals(:,(t_vals<phaseThreshold) |(abs(192-t_vals)<phaseThreshold));

        matchedIndex = size(matchedPtsCoordsR,2);
        if(matchedIndex ==0)
          continue
        end

        centersMinMaxR = zeros(1,matchedIndex);
        cmmIndexR = 1;
        for a = 1:matchedIndex;
          if(a==1)
            avgPosition = matchedPtsCoordsR(:,a);
            centersMinMaxR(1,1) =1;
          else
            currentPosition = matchedPtsCoordsR(:,a);


            %also very slow----------------------------------------------
            distance = sum(abs(currentPosition-avgPosition));
            %------------------------------------------------------------
            if(distance>4) % We are now likely in a different segment.
              centersMinMaxR(2,cmmIndexR) = a-1;
              cmmIndexR = cmmIndexR + 1;
              centersMinMaxR(1,cmmIndexR) = a;
            end
            avgPosition = matchedPtsCoordsR(:,a);
          end
        end

        centersMinMaxR(2,cmmIndexR) = a;
        centersR = round(sum(centersMinMaxR)/2);

        %//...do stuff with centersR
                    %//I end up concatenating all the centersR into a 
                    %//large vector arrray with the start and end of 
                    %//each segment.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, MatLab Profiler is your best friend and it I assume you know about it because you know what line is bottle necking.

A quick fix to remove the double loop is to use the `:` command. Instead of using a double loop, you can use a single loop but calculate along an entire dimension for each row or column index. For a simple example:

```
m = magic(2);
slope = 5;

m =
     1     3
     4     2

m(1,:) * slope  =
     5    15

m(:,1) * slope =
     5
    20
```

Instead of using jagged arrays, use sparse arrays. Matlab has built-in support for them:

[Matlab Create Sparse Array](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html)

[Matlab Sparse Matrix Operations](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f6-8856.html)

**UPDATE**

In regard to the pro-cons of using a sparse vs normal array:
[Sparse vs Normal Array Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292437/sparse-vs-normal-array-matlab/3292470#3292470)

> Sparse matrices are a true boon for
>   the person who uses truly sparse
>   matrices, but 25% non-zeros is simply
>   not "sparse" enough for any gain in
>   most cases.

Look for more updates as I have more time to review your code :p

Comment: Thanks for the response! Some of the problems I'm having with vectorizing it lies mainly in that I'm not sure how many points I'll have for each pixel, and jagged arrays aren't really supported

Comment: @Xzhsh, instead of jagged array create sparse arrays. Matlab has built-in support for sparse arrays

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html
http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f6-8856.html

Comment: At what point is having a sparse array better than a normal array if I still have a lot of calculations to do on it, and about 25% of the array are non-zeros?